# Python FeatureAgglomeration results

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I was able to use the FeatureAgglomeration module from sklearn, but I'm not sure how to view my clusters.

Is there a way I can easily print/view the clusters?  I have around 10,000 columns reduced to 100 clusters, so is there also a method to see the top ~20 columns that make up each cluster?

My code so far:

```
agglo = cluster.FeatureAgglomeration(n_clusters = 100)
agglo.fit(df)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
agglo = cluster.FeatureAgglomeration(n_clusters = 100)
agglo.fit(df)

df_transformed = agglo.transform(df)

for r in df_transformed :
    print(r)
```

To see which features got grouped together, you can use the `FeatuteAgglomeration.labels_`.

For example, suppose you have the data (5 features per data point):

```
df = [[1,2,3,4,5]]*5
```

and you do an agglomeration to reduce it to `3` features:

```
agglo = cluster.FeatureAgglomeration(n_clusters = 3)
agglo.fit(df)
```

you can then see which features got merged by checking which indices in `FeatuteAgglomeration.labels_` have the same value:

```
for i, label in enumerate(set(agglo.labels_)):
    features_with_label = [j for j, lab in enumerate(agglo.labels_) if lab == label]
    print('Features in agglomeration {}: {}'.format(i, features_with_label))


> Features in agglomeration 0: [2, 3]
> Features in agglomeration 1: [0, 1]
> Features in agglomeration 2: [4]
```

Comment: Thanks!  From what I understand, that will perform the agglomeration on my dataset and print my new dataset with the 100 clusters.  Is there a way to view the labels and how each feature are clustered together?  Currently, when I try agglo.labels_, I'm getting a result of array([63, 95, 6, ..., 6, 6, 6])

Comment: @brie no problem. I edited the answer so you can print everything. What you see a shortened list, so you cannot see all output. You can follow my description above.

Comment: My pleasure :-)