# FeatureAgglomeration: feature_names_in and get_feature_names_out

Tags: python, scikit-learn, feature-selection

I used FeatureAgglomeration to cluster my 105x105 dataframe into 40 clusters based on Spearman. Now I want to get the output feature names using feature_names_in and [get_feature_names_out](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.FeatureAgglomeration.html?highlight=featureagglomeration#sklearn.cluster.FeatureAgglomeration.get_feature_names_out), but it does not seem to work, and I cannot find the solution anymore. This is my code:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    from sklearn.cluster import FeatureAgglomeration
    features = np.array([...])
    print(features.shape)
    >>> (105,)
    Class1_rank=pd.read_excel(r'H:\PycharmProjects\RadiomicsPipeline\Class1_rank.xlsx')
    print(Class1_rank)
    >>>                         original_shape_Elongation  ...  original_ngtdm_Strength
    original_shape_Elongation        1.000000  ...                -0.054310
    original_shape_Flatness          0.616327  ...                -0.019544
    original_shape_LeastAxisLength   0.271645  ...                -0.293157
    >>> [105 rows x 105 columns]
    print(agglo.n_features_in_)
    >>> 105
    print(agglo.feature_names_in_(Class1_rank))
    print(agglo.get_feature_names_out())
    df_reduced = agglo.transform(Class1)
```

At `print(agglo.feature_names_in_())` I get to following error:

```
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

However, `Class1_rank` is a DataFrame, and thus should not give that error? What I am doing wrong here?

What I have tried:

1. Comment `print(agglo.feature_names_in_(Class1_rank))`. Works, but then `print(agglo.get features out)` gives the following result, and not the names of the features I included.

   `['featureagglomeration0' 'featureagglomeration1' 'featureagglomeration2' 'featureagglomeration3' 'featureagglomeration4'....]`
2. Use `features` as input for both functions, gives the same error.
3. Insert the features as strings for `Class1_rank`, gives the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`feature_names_in_` is an array, not a callable, so `agglo.feature_names_in_` is correct, but parentheses after it (empty or not) is incorrect.

`get_feature_names_out()` gives names for each cluster, which are not in 1-1 correspondence with input features, so it cannot give you something like the original feature names.  You can use the `labels_` attribute to find which input features go into which output features, see e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51563446/10495893).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a way to find out which of the features in a cluster is the most representative (i.e. has the highest correlation to the other features in the cluster)? I'm thinking of an answer using `agglo.fit(Class1)` or so.